# Exclude coloured cells from SumIfs

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I have a table like this:

[image: Table for SumIfs]

I need to create some Sumifs command in VBA to exclude green cells from criteria. I have the excel formula =SUMIFS(D:D;C:C;1) and need to add somehow next condition. In VBA I have:

```
Sub TotalItems()
    Dim sum As Integer
    sum = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("D:D"), Range("C:C"), _
         3)
   MsgBox sum
End Sub
```

which returns 10.

I need to count only rows without any border colour in range "A:A". I tried to write the formula like this, but it returns an error:

```
 Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("D:D"), Range("C:C"), 3, Range("A:A").Interior.Color, 0)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What sets the color?  Is it a conditional format?

Comment: Yes, green colour is a conditional format.

Comment: Okay what is the condition that makes it green then?  You will need to use that instead.

Comment: If it is conditional formatting, then the obvious and most robust solution is to target the condition that causes green rather than the color green per se.

Comment: in column A should be unique numbers. If some of them exists in another sheet then this cell is green coloured and this row should be excluded from sumifs

Comment: Are you using a formula in the conditional formatting? if so what exactly is it?

Comment: =AND(A2<>"";COUNTIF(Sheets2!A:A;A2)=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT() no need for VBA:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C100=3)*(D1:D100)*(A1:A100 <>"")*(countif(Sheet2!A:A,A1:A100)=1))
```

Comment: @otis if this solved your question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: just for info, how could I re-write that sumproduct formula to VBA command ?